# button.OnClick listener triggers twice

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, delegates, scene-manager

My play button in scene changes the current menu scene to the actual level scene.

I added the **listener** method in the form of a delegate:

```
playLevel.onClick.AddListener(delegate { LoadLevel();})
```

Most of the times it works perfectly fine, but sometimes when I click the button the game lags for a second and the button can be clicked again therefore opening the Level scene twice.

Does anyone have any idea on how to prevent this from happening? Thanks

Comment: Disable your buttons on the onClick listener

Comment: @Style-7 I tried to make them both disabled and not interactable but it did not work: playLevel.onClick.AddListener(delegate { LoadLevel(); playLevel.enabled = false; playLevel.interactable = false;}).

Comment: It may be looks like enable (need redraw) but button will disable and user can not press twice

Comment: Tested it, does not work.

Comment: add in manifest for activity android:launchMode="singleTask"

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes:) ? Looks like your button have a multiple listeners with same method. Maybe this just happens you're click same button more than a one time in same game session.

Your Code:
playLevel.onClick.AddListener(delegate { LoadLevel();})

This code delegates your method block for a listener when you clicks EVERYTIME.
I think just try playLevel.onClick.RemoveAllListeners() or just remove a specific one (if you dont want remove all) with use playLevel.onClick.RemoveListener(-your actionCall-) before delegates a new one.